# Regarding installing Ubuntu on an empty drive

Tags: boot, usb, windows, bios

My computer (Windows 10 64-bit, BIOS) has got three drives viz. C, D and E. I plan to install Ubuntu (14.04.3) on 'E' drive.
 When I check open up My Computer, I see the Windows logo on only the C drive so:
1. Is it okay if I install Ubuntu (via live boot USB) on any of the other two drives without backing up Windows?
2. Will doing so wipe the existing data on that drive even if I partition ~50GB only for Ubuntu?
3. Will I be able to use the drive for storing files from Windows too?

Also, I should note that drive E is totally empty.
Thanks in advance for your responses.
Have a great day!

-Funky Space Monkeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An installation of Ubuntu, like and installation of Windows, will only use what you specify during the installation.  During the installation you will have the option of selecting the drive/partition where you want to install.  The selected drive/partition will be the only part that will be affected.

When you install, you actually install on a partition.  During the install process you could select a drive (one of the default options) and allow Ubuntu to automatically partition the whole drive.

Before the default installation begin you will be advised that the drive will be changed accordingly.

Or you can use an alternate option and select where you want it installed.  Performing option, you will be given the same warning/advice that changes will be made to that partition.

Ubuntu can use a Windows formatted drive/partition for reading, writing, and storing data.  However, Windows can't access a Linux partition.  While Linux can read and write to a Windows drive, you would loose some significant functionality that comes with Linux formatted drive, such as, fragmentation and limited access modes.

With Linux (just like Windows) you would have to have a boot manager (you would have to specify a boot drive).  This is a reserved space on the drive for performing the boot.  Ubuntu's default boot manage is Grub.  The Grub boot manager will work for both Windows and Linux.  It will be installed by default on the drive you select for the booting drive.  Installing the boot manager doesn't effect the data on any of the drives.